# Tracking Extension on Safari and Add-on Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-analytics, safari, firefox-addon, safari-extension

We developed our own browser add-on and I would like to track the Downloads of each extension/add-on, in Safari and Firefox respectively.

We implemented a regular Google Analytics tracking code to the company website but our programmers don't have the time to figure out how to track the specific browser downloads. Since then I've been racking my brain and the Internet for a possible solution.

Thanks to an earlier helpful thread I managed to see how many people have downloaded our Add-On in the Firefox Add-On Statistics Dashboard. Unfortunately there is no information for when the download took place.

I was hoping to solve this problem with Analytics, tried making an Event tag with the extension and tested but to no avail. I know now that the simple manual entry of the extension URL into the Event tab on Analytics doesn't work. I have to use some sort of JavaScript but I'm honestly really new to this so would appreciate any sort of advice or help that could point me in the right direction!

Comment: There is a graph that shows download time by day. On the Firefox addon stats dashboard at AMO. You want timing more precise then day?

Comment: Yes, but how can I @noitidart see our particular add-on? I only see them in general on the graph and when I type in our add-on in the search bar I get how many people use it on the right-hand side.

Comment: That info is on the first page you go to: http://i.imgur.com/4k3ZZn8.png